# How to avoid loading a data twice with Ajax jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello Stackoverflow people today I have a problem is that I'm chatting but there are times that load 2 or 3 times the same data I do not know where the error is in my ajax but I do not know if it is to update or just copy the good message here I leave the code to say what happens I hope you help me and thanks in advance

Front code (html, css, js):

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .mostrar_mensaje {
        height: 440px;
        padding: 12px;
        width: 96%;
        /* border-radius: 5px; */
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mostrar_mensaje" id="mostrar_mensaje"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var out, isScrolledToBottom;
    out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje"); // outer container of messages

    // initial load of chat                     ////**Chat post id
    cargaMensajeChat(1,llenaMensajePrimeraVez);

    // check for chatter every second
    setInterval(function() {

        isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();
        cargaMensajeChat(0,llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces);

    }, 1000);

    function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
        // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    }

    function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
        if (scrollDown)
        out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }

    //funcion carga mensajes del servidor por ajax
    function cargaMensajeChat(vFlagPrimeraVez,callback){
        var vidchat=obtenerUltimoIdChat();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "load_chat.php",
            data: {
                flagPrimeraVez : vFlagPrimeraVez,
                idchat : vidchat
            },
            success: function(data){
                callback(data);             
            }
        })
    }
    //funcion llena div primera vez
    function llenaMensajePrimeraVez(contenido){
        $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(contenido);
    }
    //funcion llena agrega solo nuevos mensajes (append)
    function llenaMensajeSiguientesVeces(contenido){
        if($.trim(contenido)!=''){
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').append(contenido);
            out = document.getElementById("mostrar_mensaje");
            scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
        }
    }
    //recorre los div del chat, todos tienen atributo id="chat", coge el ultimo que es quien tiene el mayor id
    function obtenerUltimoIdChat(){
        return $("div[idchat]:last").attr("idchat");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

code php :

```
   require("conectarbd.php");
    include ("app/data.php");

////**This file is for languages    
if (@$_COOKIE["muser"]!='') {   
    require ("languages/".userdata('language',false).".php");
} else {
    require ("languages/".$Language.".php");`enter code here`
}




$id = $_GET['v']; 
////** This is to know if the room exists   
    $DataPaste = mysql_query("SELECT * from paste WHERE pasteID=$id ");
if (mysql_num_rows($DataPaste) == 0)
{
            echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/500.png"></img><br>
            '.$Languages_136.'!</center>';

}else{ 
    //SO, recibe flag primera_vez que carga pagina
    $flagPrimeraVez = $_GET['flagPrimeraVez'];
    @$idchat = $_GET['idchat'];

    //SO, validando flag
    if($idchat!='' && $idchat>0){//SO, seria despues de la primera vez, entonces se carga solomensajes nuevos
        $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id AND id>$idchat ");            
    }else{//SO, de lo contrario solo carga todos los mensajes
        $data_chat = mysql_query("SELECT * from chat WHERE post=$id ");
    }

        if (mysql_num_rows($data_chat) == 0)
        {         
            //SO, en primera vez si no hay mensajes se muestra imagen no_messages.png       
            if($flagPrimeraVez=='1'){
                    echo '<br><br><br><center><img src="'.$sitio_url.'img/no_messages.png"></img><br>
                    '.$Languages_12.'!</center>';
            }else{//SO, de lo contrario se envia mensaje en blanco
                echo '';
            }
        }else{  

            while($res=mysql_fetch_array($data_chat)){
                    $ads=$res["ads"];
                    $pads=$res["pads"];
                    $embed=$res["link"];
                    $tipo=$res["tipo"];

/////Mensaje
                        $come[0]='';
                        $come[1]=''.$Ads_Two.'';
// // // // // // // // // // // // // // Content Type------------------------->
// // // // // // chat
                         //SO, agregando idchat
                         $type[0]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat" class="message__chat">
                                            <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                        <div id="chat" class="wall_chat_body">
                                            <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam><br>'.parseString(nl2br(bb_parse(Hashtag(''.$res["mensaje"].'')))).'</p>
                                        </div>
                                   </div>'.$come[$ads].'';
// // // // // // imagen        
                        //SO, agregando idchat
                        $type[1]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat">
                                <div class="message__img">
                                        <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                    <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                        <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                        <div class="message__text t--user">
                                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                            <img class="playgif" data-swap="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&data='.$res["post"].'" src="Thumbnails?img='.upload_image($res["id"]).'&thumbs=1&data='.$res["post"].'" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
// // // // // // audio     

                        $type[2]='<div idchat='.$res["id"].' id="chat"><div class="message__img">
                                                <img class="resize--img" src="'.date_image(''.$res["userID"].'').'" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">
                                            <div class="wall_chat_body_image">
                                                <p class="message__text"><spam class="message__username" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-user" data-id="'.$res["userID"].'" id="getUser">'.date_name_user(''.$res["userID"].'').'</spam><spam class="message__username_time">'.time_elapsed($res["time"]).'</spam></p>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                <div class="message__chat m--user">
                                    <p class="message__text t--user">
                                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-media" data-id="'.$res["id"].'" id="getMedia">
                                    <img src="img/tool.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>';    



////** Here are the chat messages   
                echo $type[$tipo];
////** This is the function for external links                  
                echo ''.External_links($res["link"]).''; 

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Would you completely translate problem description on English?

Comment: You can't repeat ids for elements, which you are not, but your logic is currently looking for a single one by id.  Given that your elements already have a shared class on them, `img_thumbnails`, you can target those with $('.img_thumbnails') for your click binding.  Then inside the click handler `this` will be the image that was clicked and you can use the attributes/properties on it to know what to do for your loading.